# The image is not rendered in the page.I want each of the items on the Itemlist component to have an image match.I only tried with the Lenovo item

Tags: reactjs

Here is my ItemList component with the rest of the components.All my components are in the App.js component.The image is in the source folder same as the App.js component.

```
class ItemsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {total:0,

  items: [
    {image:{require('./image.jpg')},name:"Lenovo",description:"Core i5 - 4gb ram - 256gb 
 SSD", price: 540},
    {name:"Dell",description:"Core i7 - 8gb ram - 1tb HDD",  price: 700},
    {name:"Asus",description:"Core i3 - 4gb ram - 512gb HDD",  price: 429}
    ]}
```

Comment: Share your render method too please.

Comment: render() {
    var theThis = this;
    var items = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
      return(
          <Item name={item.name} description={item.description} price={item.price}
         handleShow={theThis.showDetails}
        handleTotal={theThis.calculate}
         />
        );
    });

Comment: I can't see a return statement here.Also, where are you consuming your `items.image` variable?

Comment: @Samet M This is where I'm consuming my items.image variable         <img src='./image.png' alt="laptop"/>
         <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
          <p>{this.props.description}</p>
          <button onClick={this.buy}>Buy</button>
          <button onClick={this.show}>Show</button>
          <span> ${this.props.price}</span>
          <span> (Cart: {this.state.amount} items.)</span>

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
import LenovoImage from './image.jpg';   /* or whatever image path */

class ItemsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {total:0,

  items: [
    {image:LenovoImage,name:"Lenovo",description:"Core i5 - 4gb ram - 256gb 
 SSD", price: 540},
    {name:"Dell",description:"Core i7 - 8gb ram - 1tb HDD",  price: 700},
    {name:"Asus",description:"Core i3 - 4gb ram - 512gb HDD",  price: 429}
    ]
}
```

Comment: can i give you my repo?

Comment: render() {
    var theThis = this;
    var items = this.state.items.map(function(item)
     {
      return(
        <image src="{'./image.png'}" Item name={item.name} description={item.description} price={item.price}
        handleShow={theThis.showDetails}
        handleTotal={theThis.calculate}
         />
        );
    });

Comment: Here is my corrected repo  https://github.com/edwin001-tech/Simple-Stocksales-App.git